# How to update MSRP in Magento using their REST API

Tags: rest, api, magento

I am trying to update the MSRP, using the Magento REST API, of an item in Magento 2.3 with a Dell Boomi integration process. I have successfully updated the base price of an item but I have not found any information on updating the MSRP. Does anyone know how to do this or what the endpoint URL would be that I should use?

Any ideas are appreciated.
Regards,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update the MSRP in Magento with the following Postman request URL & payload.

/rest/all/V1/products/product_sku 
{"product": { 
    "custom_attributes": 
    [ 
    { "attribute_code": "msrp", 
    "value": "252.58" } 
    ] 
    } 
} 
Regards, Joe